# Webpack - Unable to use bootstrap tooltips

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am using angular-cli and Webpack for an Angular2 project.

I have loaded jquery, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js files globally from the angular-cli.json file. The config is given below-:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
```

I have also downloaded the bootstrap typings files from [DefinetlyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/bootstrap) and added them as a reference using `/// <reference path="@types/bootstrap" />` in the component I want.

But when I am executing the tooltip initialization function
`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

I keep getting the errors-:

```
Typeerror_handler.js:53TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery__(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HeaderComponent.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:759:73)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:74:74)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:69363:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:69456:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:69363:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:69456:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:51541:20)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:36682:84
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Can someone help me out with this ? I used the same approach for when I had to use typeahead.js and that worked flawlessly, but why isn't it working here ?

Comment: `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"` checkout the path. Does this have a real `js` folder or does the `bootstrap.min.js` actually exist?

Comment: @Jai Yes it exists.

Comment: @ng.newbie did you find a solution for this ??

Comment: @DavidBracoly yes I did, at least for my project. I will upload it in a few days

Comment: Please share your solution. I'm facing a similar issue with another third party component.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the similar problem by using a `new Function()`.
Sample of code:

```
new Function('cell', 'jQuery("[data-toggle=tooltip]", cell).tooltip();')(cellNode);
```